# Dynamic Content ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I have looked everywhere for a tutorial on this how do I go about making a aspx page that I pass an ID for a item into so the url would be item.aspx?id=1042 and it would display data from sql database for item #1042. Does anyone have any information on how I do this, any articles or tutorials would be wonderful.

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a tutorial. Just use the Request.Querystring property like this:

```
int id = int.Parse(Request.Querystring("id").ToString());

// then use the id int in a db query
```

Good luck!

Comment: I believe it should be
int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking at ASP.NET AJAX.  Basically you send an `XMLHttpRequest` (AJAX) back to the server with the id parameter, parse it like Paul Sasik said, then query the db and render the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys())
{
    var values = Request.QueryString.GetValues("id");
    if (values != null)
    {
        var id= Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
    }
}
```